# Oracle Golden Gate Version 12.1.2 DBLOGIN throws error

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I am not able to login in GGS_OWNER from within GGSCI. I am able to login from  sqlplus but when I try to login thorugh GGSCI it throws an error:

> `GG Version: 12.1.2
>   Database version: 12c
>   Type of replication: Integrated Capture
>   Replication setup: Unidirectional DML replication`

```
Source Context :
SourceModule            : [ggapp.util.pcs]
SourceID                : [/scratch/aime1/adestore/views/aime1_adc4150327/oggcore/OpenSys/src/gglib/ggapp/pcsutl.c]
SourceFunction          : [AbendHandler]
SourceLine              : [1005]
ThreadBacktrace         : [21] elements
                      : [/ggsadmin/app/ggate/12.1.2/libgglog.so(CMessageContext::AddThreadContext()+0x1e) [0x7f79191a286e]]
                      : [/ggsadmin/app/ggate/12.1.2/libgglog.so(CMessageFactory::CreateMessage(CSourceContext*, unsigned int, ...)+0x340) [0x7f791919d580]]
                      : [/ggsadmin/app/ggate/12.1.2/libgglog.so(_MSG_ERR_SIGNAL_RECEIVED(CSourceContext*, int, char const*, CMessageFactory::MessageDisposition)+0x3b) [0x7f791918078b]]
                      : [ggsci [0x50f653]]
                      : [/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x36b940eca0]]
                      : [/lib64/libpthread.so.0(pthread_mutex_lock+0) [0x36b9408dd0]]
                      : [ggsci(ggs::gglib::MultiThreading::Mutex::Lock()+0x9) [0x5449c9]]
                      : [ggsci(CContextItem::operator char const*() const+0x15) [0x4e2b3f]]
                      : [ggsci(DBOCI_init_connection_logon(ggs::gglib::ggapp::CLoginName const&, ggs::gglib::ggapp::CDBObjName<(DBObjType)12> const&, char const*, int, int, int, char*)+0x1e5) [0x553b85]]
                      : [ggsci [0x566ba4]]
                      : [ggsci(gl_db_login(char const*, char const*,   ggs::gglib::ggapp::CDBObjName<(DBObjType)11>&, ggs::gglib::ggapp::CDBObjName<(DBObjType)12>&, short, char (&) [2048])+0x5f) [0x566edf]]
                      : [ggsci [0x4a4d12]]
                      : [ggsci(GGSCIDB_get_command(char const*, char const*, char const*, short, short, char (&) [2048])+0x11b) [0x4a525b]]
                       : [ggsci(do_cmd(char*, unsigned long, char*, unsigned long)+0xb14) [0x4dd654]]
                      : [ggsci [0x4e145b]]
                      : [ggsci(ggs::gglib::MultiThreading::MainThread::ExecMain()+0x4f) [0x54241f]]
                      : [ggsci(ggs::gglib::MultiThreading::Thread::RunThread(ggs::gglib::MultiThreading::Thread::ThreadArgs*)+0x104) [0x542624]]
                      : [ggsci(ggs::gglib::MultiThreading::MainThread::Run(int, char**)+0x8b) [0x54273b]]
                      : [ggsci(main+0x3f) [0x4bc94f]]
                      : [/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4) [0x36b841d9f4]]
                      : [ggsci [0x49c379]]

2015-09-24 08:35:18  ERROR   OGG-01117  Received signal: Segmentation violation (11).

2015-09-24 08:35:18  ERROR   OGG-01668  PROCESS ABENDING.
```

Segmentation fault

Comment: Thank you all...was able to solve this issue after setting the oracle home correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You may be experiencing an issue with you path. Take a look at the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Make sure it's pointing to your ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion that you should always login to GGSCI from OGG_HOME path only. Because, when you login to GGSCI, GGSCI tries to read the params from the current path (and not the absolute path). This may lead to a few params not getting loaded when you login to GGSCI from any location other than OGG_HOME.

i.e.

> cd $OGG_HOME
>
> ./ggsci

BUT NOT AS :

> cd $OGG_HOME/dirprm  (for example)
>
> ../ggsci

Answer (score -1):

I hope by now you would have figured out the way to fix this issue; would be better if you could share the DBLOGIN command you ran which led to error.

Below is the command format:
DBLOGIN SOURCEDB AAA USERID XXX, PASSWORD YYY, SESSIONCHARSET latin1

These links may be of use too:
SOURCEDB : https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/gg_parameters149.htm#GWURF649

DBLOGIN : https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/ggsci_commands059.htm#GWURF251